# Store the addresses of the function parameters

Tags: c++

How can I store the addresses of the arguments,
and make the function use them instead of the values it was initialized with?

This is not a running code, just the goal I would like to achieve.

```
class Class {
private:
    Function function_; // e.g. :  int Sum(int a, int b) { return a+b; } ;
    std::tuple<Args...> args; //  a,b provided are static consts.

public:
    Class(Function _function, Args... _args) :  
        function_ { std::forward<Function>(_function) } 
        args{std::make_tuple( std::forward<Args>(_args)...) }
    {}

    void run_fucntion()
    {
       // use the addresses of a,b
       function_( *p_a, *p_b ... ) //   How do I do that?
    }
```

Comment: try accessing the stack before the function is called

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Doing `*p_a` or `args1` is the same thing.

Comment: Something like [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to call a function with a tuple that is expanded as the arguments?

Comment: Also to note is that you can't have `std::tuple<Args...> args;` without making `Class` a variadic template.  Good news is with CTAD that's a lot less of an issue then it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::apply` to apply the tuple of **reference** (not pointer but it do refer to the original object)

---

note: not sure what `p_a` and `p_b` supposed to be, but you can add then to the tuple with `std::tuple_cat`

---

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename F,typename ... Args>
class Class {
private:
    F function;
    std::tuple<Args...> args;

public:
    Class(F&& function, Args&&... _args):
        function(std::forward<F>(function)), 
        args{std::forward<Args>(_args)...}
    {}

    decltype(auto) run_fucntion()
    {
       return std::apply(function,args);
    }
};

template <typename F,typename...Args>
Class(F&&,Args&&...) -> Class<F&&,Args&&...>;

auto f(int x){
    return Class([](int a,int b){return a+b;},1,x).run_fucntion();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jnY9sod94

---

---

---

if this is what you want, you can even pack them at first place

```cpp
template <typename F,typename ... Args>
class Class {
private:
    std::function<std::invoke_result_t<F,Args...>()> function;
public:
    Class(F&& f, Args&&...args)
    :function([&]{return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}){}

    decltype(auto) run_fucntion(){
        return function();
    }
};

template <typename F,typename...Args>
Class(F&&,Args&&...) -> Class<F&&,Args&&...>;
```